# Failed to execute when trying to open

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I'm working with tkinter. Somewhat finished a GUI I'm trying to create. I want to give it a test run to other people within my facility. I'm using pyinstaller to make it an .exe.

My command that I used: pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=Skugo.ico Beta.pyw

It builds it and everything but when I try to open it up it gives the error "Fatal Error Detected. Failed to execute script Beta."

I also tried using auto-py-to-exe. Same thing happened after it was built.

I've been looking and some said that it might be due to their script but there aren't any errors that pop up on mine.

My Script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

import pandas as pd

from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import csv
import os


class aSide(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.resizable(True, True)

        window_height = 530
        window_width = 705
        screen_w = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_h = self.winfo_screenheight()

        x = int((screen_w / 2) - (window_width / 2))
        y = int((screen_h / 2) - (window_height / 2))

        self.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x, y))
        self.iconbitmap('Skugo.ico')
        self.title("Testing A-Side")

        self.today = date.today()
        self.yesterday = self.today - timedelta(days=1)
        self.todayIsMonday = self.today - timedelta(days=3)

        self.lead = Label(self, text='Lead', fg='Green', font=32)
        self.lead.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=7, pady=5)
        self.date = Label(self, text=self.today.strftime("%x"), fg='Blue', font=24)
        self.date.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=7)

        self.savetree = Button(self, text='Save Sheet', command=lambda: (self.savheet(), self.savecsvSheet()))
        self.savetree.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        self.tree()

        self.editbtn = Button(self, text='EDIT', fg='navy blue', command=self.edit)
        self.editbtn.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=5, pady=5)
        self.removebtn = Button(self, text='REMOVE', fg='red', command=self.removeTeammate)
        self.removebtn.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=7, pady=10)

        self.station = Label(self, text='Station #')
        self.station.grid(row=8, column=1)
        self.b_l = Label(self, text='Break--Lunch')
        self.b_l.grid(row=8, column=2)
        self.names = Label(self, text='Teammate')
        self.names.grid(row=8, column=3)
        self.start = Label(self, text='Start Date')
        self.start.grid(row=8, column=4)
        self.agency = Label(self, text='Agency')
        self.agency.grid(row=8, column=5)
        self.hw = Label(self, text='Hours Work')
        self.hw.grid(row=8, column=6)
        self.note = Label(self, text='Notes')
        self.note.grid(row=8, column=7)

        self.entStation = Entry(self, width=3)
        self.entStation.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.entb_l = Entry(self, width=4)
        self.entb_l.grid(row=9, column=2)
        self.entNames = Entry(self)
        self.entNames.grid(row=9, column=3)
        self.entStart = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entStart.grid(row=9, column=4)
        self.entAgency = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entAgency.grid(row=9, column=5)
        self.enthw = Entry(self, width=3)
        self.enthw.grid(row=9, column=6)
        self.entNote = Entry(self)
        self.entNote.grid(row=9, column=7)

        self.addteammate = Button(self, text='ADD TEAMAMTE', fg='green', command=self.addTeammate)
        self.addteammate.grid(row=10, column=1, columnspan=25, pady=20)

        self.saveSheet()
        self.savecsvSheet()

    def tree(self):
        self.my_tree = ttk.Treeview(self)

        self.my_tree['columns'] = (
            "Station #", "Break_Lunch", "Teammate", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work", "Notes")

        self.my_tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
        self.my_tree.column('Station #', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
        self.my_tree.column('Break_Lunch', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
        self.my_tree.column('Teammate', anchor=CENTER, width=120)
        self.my_tree.column('Start Date', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
        self.my_tree.column('Agency', anchor=CENTER, width=120)
        self.my_tree.column('Hours Work', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
        self.my_tree.column('Notes', anchor=CENTER, width=120)

        self.my_tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Station #', text='Station #', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Break_Lunch', text='Break--Lunch', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Teammate', text='Teammates', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Start Date', text='Start Date', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Agency', text='Agency', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Hours Work', text='Hours Work', anchor=CENTER)
        self.my_tree.heading('Notes', text='Notes', anchor=CENTER)

        self.my_tree.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=7, pady=10, padx=10)

        os.chdir('Csv Files')
        self.path = os.getcwd()

        if date.today().weekday() == 0:
            with open('Testing A-Side ' + self.todayIsMonday.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + '.csv',
                      newline='')as file:
                reader = csv.DictReader(file)
                for col in reader:
                    station = col['Station #']
                    b_l = col['Break_Lunch']
                    name = col['Teammate']
                    start = col['Start Date']
                    agency = col['Agency']
                    hw = col['Hours Work']
                    note = col['Notes']
                    self.my_tree.insert('', 0, values=(station, b_l, name, start, agency, hw, note))

        elif date.today().weekday() != 0:
            with open("Testing A-Side " + self.yesterday.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + ".csv",
                      newline='')as f:
                reader = csv.DictReader(f)
                for col in reader:
                    station = col['Station #']
                    b_l = col['Break_Lunch']
                    name = col['Teammate']
                    start = col['Start Date']
                    agency = col['Agency']
                    hw = col['Hours Work']
                    note = col['Notes']
                    self.my_tree.insert('', 0, values=(station, b_l, name, start, agency, hw, note))

        self.parent = os.path.dirname(self.path)
        os.chdir(self.parent)

    def saveSheet(self):
        # self.prod_total = Label(self, text='Production Total')
        # self.prod_total.grid(row=1, column=6, columnspan=7)
        # self.total = Entry(self, width=5)
        # self.total.grid(row=2, column=6, columnspan=7)
        # self.save_total = Button(self, text='Save Production Total', command=self.saveProdTotal)
        # self.save_total.grid(row=3, column=6, columnspan=7, pady=5)

        os.chdir('Teammate Sheet')
        self.path = os.getcwd()

        self.excolumns = ["Station #", "Break_Lunch", "Teammate", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work",
                          "Notes", ]  # , "Production Total"]
        self.info = [self.my_tree.item(item)['values'] for item in self.my_tree.get_children()]
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.info, columns=self.excolumns)
        self.df.to_excel("Testing A-Side " + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + ".xlsx",
                         engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)

        self.parent = os.path.dirname(self.path)
        os.chdir(self.parent)

    def savecsvSheet(self):
        os.chdir('Csv Files')
        self.path1 = os.getcwd()

        self.excolumns1 = ["Station #", "Break_Lunch", "Teammate", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work",
                           "Notes"]  # , "Production Total"]
        self.info1 = [self.my_tree.item(item)['values'] for item in self.my_tree.get_children()]
        self.df1 = pd.DataFrame(self.info1, columns=self.excolumns1)
        self.df1.to_csv("Testing A-Side " + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + ".csv", index=False)

        self.parent1 = os.path.dirname(self.path1)
        os.chdir(self.parent1)

    def addTeammate(self):
        os.chdir('Csv Files')
        self.path4 = os.getcwd()

        with open('Testing A-Side ' + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + '.csv', 'a',
                  newline='')as file:
            w = csv.writer(file)
            w.writerow([self.entStation.get(), self.entb_l.get(), self.entNames.get(), self.entStart.get(),
                        self.entAgency.get(),
                        self.enthw.get(), self.entNote.get()])

        self.my_tree.insert('', 0, values=(
        self.entStation.get(), self.entb_l.get(), self.entNames.get(), self.entStart.get(), self.entAgency.get(),
        self.enthw.get(), self.entNote.get()))

        self.parent4 = os.path.dirname(self.path4)
        os.chdir(self.parent4)

        self.entStation.delete(0, END)
        self.entb_l.delete(0, END)
        self.entNames.delete(0, END)
        self.entStart.delete(0, END)
        self.entAgency.delete(0, END)
        self.enthw.delete(0, END)
        self.entNote.delete(0, END)

        self.entStation.focus_set()

        self.savecsvSheet()

    def edit(self):
        self.updateteammate = Button(self, text='UPDATE', fg='navy blue', command=self.updateSheet)
        self.updateteammate.grid(row=11, column=1, columnspan=7)

        self.entStation.delete(0, END)
        self.entb_l.delete(0, END)
        self.entNames.delete(0, END)
        self.entStart.delete(0, END)
        self.entAgency.delete(0, END)
        self.enthw.delete(0, END)
        self.entNote.delete(0, END)

        self.select = self.my_tree.focus()
        self.val = self.my_tree.item(self.select, 'values')

        self.entStation.insert(0, self.val[0])
        self.entb_l.insert(0, self.val[1])
        self.entNames.insert(0, self.val[2])
        self.entStart.insert(0, self.val[3])
        self.entAgency.insert(0, self.val[4])
        self.enthw.insert(0, self.val[5])
        self.entNote.insert(0, self.val[6])

    def updateSheet(self):
        self.select = self.my_tree.focus()
        self.my_tree.item(self.select, text='', values=(
            self.entStation.get(), self.entb_l.get(), self.entNames.get(), self.entStart.get(), self.entAgency.get(),
            self.enthw.get(), self.entNote.get()))

        os.chdir('Csv Files')
        self.path2 = os.getcwd()

        with open('Testing A-Side ' + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + '.csv', 'r')as read:
            reader = csv.DictReader(read)
            data = list(reader)

        with open('Testing A-Side ' + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + '.csv', 'w',
                  newline='')as write:
            headers = ["Station #", "Break_Lunch", "Teammate", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work", "Notes"]

            writer = csv.DictWriter(write, fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writeheader()

            for row in data:
                if row['Teammate'] == self.entNames.get():
                    row['Station #'] = self.entStation.get()
                    row['Break_Lunch'] = self.entb_l.get()
                    row['Start Date'] = self.entStart.get()
                    row['Agency'] = self.entAgency.get()
                    row['Hours Work'] = self.enthw.get()
                    row['Notes'] = self.entNote.get()
                writer.writerow(row)

        messagebox.showinfo("Data Updated!", self.entNames.get() + " data has been updated.")

        self.parent2 = os.path.dirname(self.path)
        os.chdir(self.parent2)

        self.entStation.delete(0, END)
        self.entb_l.delete(0, END)
        self.entNames.delete(0, END)
        self.entStart.delete(0, END)
        self.entAgency.delete(0, END)
        self.enthw.delete(0, END)
        self.entNote.delete(0, END)

        self.entStation.focus_set()

        self.updateteammate.grid_remove()

        self.savecsvSheet()

    def removeTeammate(self):
        self.selected = self.my_tree.focus()
        self.values = self.my_tree.item(self.selected, 'values')

        os.chdir('Csv Files')
        self.path3 = os.getcwd()

        with open('Testing A-Side ' + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + '.csv', 'r') as read:
            reader = csv.DictReader(read)
            data = list(reader)

        with open('Testing A-Side ' + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + '.csv',
                  'w', newline='')as write:
            headers = ["Station #", "Break_Lunch", "Teammate", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work", "Notes"]

            writer = csv.DictWriter(write, fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writeheader()

            for row in data:
                if row['Teammate'] == self.entNames.get():
                    continue
                writer.writerow(row)

        self.parent3 = os.path.dirname(self.path3)
        os.chdir(self.parent3)

        with open('Removed.csv', 'a', newline='')as r:
            w = csv.writer(r)
            w.writerow([self.values[2], self.values[3], self.values[4]])

        messagebox.showinfo("Data Removed!", self.entNames.get() + "'s data has been removed.")

        self.my_tree.delete(self.selected)

        self.entStation.delete(0, END)
        self.entb_l.delete(0, END)
        self.entNames.delete(0, END)
        self.entStart.delete(0, END)
        self.entAgency.delete(0, END)
        self.enthw.delete(0, END)
        self.entNote.delete(0, END)

        self.entStation.focus_set()

        self.updateteammate.grid_remove()

        self.savecsvSheet()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = aSide()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This could be any number of fatal errors. But if the script runs fine before it's converted to .exe, it might be a missing package. I had an issue with a part of a package, once, that was not included automatically in pyinstaller. If you change the command to: `pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn Beta.pyw -F`, does it work?

Comment: @MartinWettstein It does the same thing :(

Comment: Then might it be the files? Your script requires files (e.g. Skugo.ico) to run. If these files are not in the same folder as the .exe, it might crash. You could add them as additional resources in pyinstaller, so you don't need to distribute the files.

Comment: I have all the files/folder I need within the same directory. I used auto-py-to-exe to add my other folders my .exe and still same outcome.

Comment: There's one last resort when this happens to me: Change it to `.py`, convert it again, and run it in the console. Then, you get the Traceback of the error in the console and might find out where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was that my pandas module apparently wasn't installed. I just went ahead and copied my script and made a whole new directory for it and pasted it there. Then I pip installed pandas again. When I ran my .exe file through the command prompt it would give me errors saying pandas module was not found.

I would like to thank [@Martin Wettstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13969611/martin-wettstein) for all his help guide me through the issue I was having.